# CakePHP: how can I access Cake functionality from a simple PHP script on the same website

Tags: php, cakephp

I maintain a website that is 15 years old and was originally written in sprawling PHP code. I have recently grafted on a backend implemented in CakePHP which I placed into it's own folder on the main website (all urls look like `http://www.mysite.com/console/<cake stuff>`).

This backend is working fine and I have lots of useful functionality in the CakePHP part - but now I would like to be able to access some of this functionality from the main site since it seems a waste to reimplement in vanilla PHP.

Of course one option would be to the Cake code produce results in JSON and then in a PHP page I could use curl call the action, in pseudo code:

```
$data = curl('http://mysite.com/console/accounts/data.json');
$accounts = json_decode($data);
```

But it seems very inefficient to be using curl to page *within the same site*.
Instead, I would like to have a class that would work something like this:

```
require('clever_stuff.php');
$cakeAccessor = new CakeAccessor(<settings>);
$accounts = $cakeAccessor->requestAction('orders','data');
```

I've searched online and can't find anything. But before trying to implement my own class (which I hope should be possible by coping the code in shell scripts intended for calling Cake functionality from the command line) I wondered if anyone new of a open-source module that already does this.

Please note: it isn't feasible to move all the pages from the main site to the webroot directory.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly subclass the [`CakeResponse`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php) class, modify its `send` method to stop automatic output, and then use a modified version of `webroot/index.php` to Dispatch to your custom class, and retrieve Cake's output from it.